# UICollectionView gets loading before delegate method call for web service

Tags: ios, objective-c

From the web service I can pull the response and parse it. I can get the desired parsing values and pass it to controller. However the collection view gets load before the delegate method call. This result in null values passed to collection view. How can i call the delegate method first and later the collection view?. My code as below,

```
//Webservices.m
//calling web service url and assigning to my delegate method
[self.myDelegate getmethodCallString:myDictionary];

//parser.m
-(NSMutableArray *)brandMenuParser:(NSDictionary*)dict{
    NSMutableArray *arrData = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    NSArray *categoryarray =[dict objectForKey:@"categories"];
    for (int i =0; i<[categoryarray count]; i++){
        NSMutableDictionary *dictData = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
        NSDictionary *dict1 =[categoryarray objectAtIndex:i];
       [dictData setObject:[dict1 valueForKey:@"category_name"] forKey:@"product"];
       [arrData addObject:dictData];
    return arrData;
}

//viewcontroller.h
@property(nonatomic,strong)APIParser *parsevalues;

//viewcontroller.m
- (void)viewDidLoad {
   [self getWebCall];
}
-(void) getWebCall{
   webCall = [[Webservices alloc]init];
//delegate call
   webCall.myDelegate =self;
}
-(void)getmethodCallString:(NSMutableDictionary *)myDictonaryCall{
   parsevalues =[[APIParser alloc]init];
   NSMutableArray *pars=[parsevalues myParser: myDictonaryCall];
   for(int i = 0; i < [pars count]; i++){
      namearray = [[pars objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"product"];
      NSLog(@"namearray%@",namearray);  // Here i can get the correct values 
//Added reload for collection view
     [collectionview reloadData];
   }
}

//collection view
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    ListCollectionCell *cell;
    UILabel *celllabel =[[UILabel alloc]init];
    celllabel.frame =CGRectMake(0, 220, cellview.frame.size.width, 25);
// loads before delegate call as null values
    celllabel.text =[namearray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; 
    [cellview addSubview:celllabel];
    cell.backgroundView =cellview;
return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just call [collectionView reloadData] whenever you finish parsing your data.

Comment: Added the `reloadData` as you mentioned after the `namearray` parsing. I got an error as `-[__NSCFString objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fa9f0d7e120` and app crashed.

Comment: Its telling you that you are trying to send a method "object at index" to a object of type NSString, and thats why your app crashes. Make sure that you get valid data and that you parse it correctly. My guess is that it is your "namearray" that is not actually an array, but a string.

Comment: `namearray` is a 'NSMutableArray'. After parsing the result is stored in `namearray` and send to the `UILabel` in collection view as in in code. I used a break point and found first its in 'NSMutableArray` after the parsing the it shows me as `(__NSCFString *)`.

Comment: Set the breakpoint in your "cellForItemAtIndex", and in the console print "po [namearray class]". What's the output?

Comment: I used a break point and found first its in 'NSMutableArray` after the parsing the it shows me as (__NSCFString *)

Comment: So you just confirmed that your parsing doesn't work correctly. Instead of creating an NSArray it creates an NSString. If you fix your parser everything else will work fine.